# Function to group numbers of similar range together?

Tags: python, math

I have a list of numbers that I want to separate into different groups based on how close they are with each other

```
List1=[1.8, 1.1, 1.9, 11, 9, 10, 36, 39, 44, 20]
```

When I look at this list, I know immediately there’s 4 groups of numbers, the first 3 fall into one group, next 3 fall into one group, the next 3 falls into one group, and the last number (20) belongs in a group of its own. I’m not exactly sure how I’m doing this, but I think other people would probably agree with me

What am I doing in my head to determine this? Is there a function to do this in python?

Comment: In N-dimensions, this is called clustering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis. Here's a thread about applying some techniques to 1D: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/determine-different-clusters-of-1d-data-from-database/40475

Comment: It seems like you're intending them to be split whenever the difference between the numbers is greater than some threshold. You could just iterate the list, and check the difference between the numbers, splitting if the difference is too high.

Comment: What is the threshold in this case?

Comment: The example is throwing you for a loop. What if 25 and 15 were in there as well? Would this make groups #2, #3 and #4 into one big group? You can repeat that question, the threshold is arbitrary. The challenge here is to come up with a rule that matches your intuition, there is no one 'best answer'. I would look at gaps that exceed the average gap by a certain number of standard deviations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example data and intuition corresponds with the following rule: "Two values are in the same group, if the distance between them is no more than 1 standard deviation removed from the mean distances between values in the entire group."

Here's code that says the same:

```
from statistics import stdev

# sort the data, for simplicity
data = sorted([1.8, 1.1, 1.9, 11, 9, 10, 36, 39, 44, 20])

# create a list of the gaps between the consecutive values
gaps = [y - x for x, y in zip(data[:-1], data[1:])]
# have python calculate the standard deviation for the gaps
sd = stdev(gaps)

# create a list of lists, put the first value of the source data in the first
lists = [[data[0]]]
for x in data[1:]:
    # if the gap from the current item to the previous is more than 1 SD
    # Note: the previous item is the last item in the last list
    # Note: the '> 1' is the part you'd modify to make it stricter or more relaxed
    if (x - lists[-1][-1]) / sd > 1:
        # then start a new list
        lists.append([])
    # add the current item to the last list in the list
    lists[-1].append(x)

print(lists)
```

The output is:

```
[[1.1, 1.8, 1.9], [9, 10, 11], [20], [36, 39, 44]]
```

I'm assuming that the sort order is of no importance.

To answer my own question in the comments, if you add 15 and 25, the result is:

```
[[1.1, 1.8, 1.9], [9, 10, 11], [15], [20], [25], [36, 39], [44]]
```

Note that, after adding 15 and 25, the standard deviation changed, so 44 got split off in its own little group as well. If you add 17 to that, it becomes:

```
[[1.1, 1.8, 1.9], [9, 10, 11], [15, 17, 20], [25], [36, 39], [44]]
```

Or, if you don't add 17, but instead demand that the distance is no more than 1.6 SD:

```
[[1.1, 1.8, 1.9], [9, 10, 11, 15, 20, 25], [36, 39, 44]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, in the last example, do you feel it would be more intuitive to group [[1.1, 1.8, 1.9], [9,10,11], [15,20,25], [36,39,44]]? I agree the real challenge here is defining the intuition which might change when the data changes too

Comment: If you can't find a value for the number of standard deviations that matches your expectation, perhaps that one metric isn't enough. Another measure I can think of is the size of the groups - I can imagine doing a second run over the results, merging the smallest groups, depending on a combined metric including their size and distance to their neighbours. But I think the implementation as given above is the best *simple* solution.

Answer (score 0):

Very messy and long at the moment, but I believe this accomplishes what you wanted:

```
def define_groups(l, threshold = .4):
    groups = {}
    its = 0
    for i in l:
        numbers_except = list(l)
        del numbers_except[(l.index(i))]
        for x in range(len(numbers_except)):
            if percentage_diff(i, numbers_except[x]) < threshold:
                try:
                    groups[its].append(numbers_except[x])
                except:
                    groups[its] = [numbers_except[x]]
                del l[l.index(numbers_except[x])]
        try:
            groups[its].append(i)
        except:
            groups[its] = [i]
        its += 1
    print(groups)

def percentage_diff(a, b):
    return abs(abs(a-b)) / max([a,b])
```

`In [0]: define_groups([1.8, 1.1, 1.9, 11, 9, 10, 36, 39, 44, 20])
{0: [1.1, 1.9, 1.8], 1: [9, 10, 11], 2: [39, 44, 36], 3: [20]}`

The threshold amount can be very easily modified to include just the change in value, but then it is out of proportion from the lower numbers to the higher values, and it would create groups that don't match how you described. That is why I used a percentage change check.

Comment: thanks, that looks like a good solution in this case, but what was the process for you to get the .4 number? for example in another list I have: list2= [0.1, 0.8, 13, 21, 150, 130, 1000, 1800], I think it would make sense to group 0.1 and 0.8, then 13 and 21, then 150 and 130, then 1000 and 1800

Comment: I simply used whatever worked best for your numbers. For that set, a percentage change value of .9 would work besides correct grouping the 1000. But that means you would have to set the percentage value yourself based on the numbers. Not sure if that would always work for your problem though

Comment: Another solution I could code for you would generate a difference between all numbers using abs(), not percentage, and it would group on the average of the difference being the smallest for each group